# Accessing MVC 4 MembershipProvider in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-membership

I have an MVC application which creates an SQL DB using Entity Framework, and provides access to this via a WCF DataService. I also have a WPF application which I would like to use to control the MembershipProvider functions of the MVC application, e.g. register new users, update usernames/passwords, etc.

I've looked over a mess of material on using the MembershipProvider functions to provide security within a WPF app, but I'm struggling to find anything on how to access the MVC functions *from* WPF.

Is this possible using a WCF DataService, or something similar?

Comment: You found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx ?